# ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: User::Admin is not a subclass of User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So, most of the questions I have found with this involve people not wanting to use single table inheritance.

**I do**, and now it is causing a little bit of a headache.

I get the titled error:

`ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: User::Admin is not a subclass of User` when debugging my code.

The issue is, in both the console and in my rspec tests, the code works fine (all specs pass and they reference this class multiple times.

From the console I can create an instance of `User::Admin`.

So this leads me to believe that the class is not being loaded by the Rails "Magic", but I can't for the life of me find out why.

The class resides in `app/models/user/admin.rb'

```
class User::Admin < User
end
```

`app/modles/user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with rails autoloading and STI. I documented what's happening here: https://flatironsdevelopment.com/blog/rails-devise-not-a-subclass-of-user

Long story short, I had to monkeypatch in development or when Rails.application.config.eager_load is false to get the right classes to load within gems. For me, it had to do with Devise and the method `def self.find_sti_class(type_name)` which I overrode in the User model to return the applications instance of the User class, not the version that devise was using.